# I want to extract only text from html, but when I use html2text function, I get an output error

Tags: python, web-crawler

[image: this is error output]

```
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

with open('crawlingweb.csv')as f:
    content=f.readlines()
    content=[x.strip()for x in content]

for i in range(125):
    url=content[i]
    req=requests.get(url)
    html=req.text
    raw=html2text.html2text(html)
    print(raw)
```

Is there any way to fix the output error while using html2text function?

Comment: try ```raw=html2text.html2text(html).encode('utf-8')```

Comment: BTW: `for url in content:` is more readable. And if you want to end after 125 urls - `for url in content[:125]:`

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which url makes problem and check what this url display in web browser. And you could add this url in question so we could see this page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to interpret retrieved text as UTF-8 string:

```
raw=html2text.html2text(html)
utf8_text=raw.encode('utf-8')
print(utf8_text)
```